# Drawables with Layers - only resize one of them - Android

Tags: android, position, drawable, scale, layer

I want to combine 2 Drawables into one as seen in my mockup:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZHkj.jpg

I want to use the drawable as a background of a TextView Object.
I tried it that way:

```
            Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
            layers[0] = new ColorDrawable(0xffff0000);
            layers[1] = resources.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now);
            LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
            setBackgroundDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

Unfortunately, with that code, the Drawable from layer 1 is scaled to the size of the TextView Object.

Now my question:

How can I tell Dalvik to position layer 1 always vertically centered and horizontally right and not to scale it to the size of the other layer? (like seen in my mockup).

Thanks a lot in advance!